# refreshing anchorpane javafx

Tags: java, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I have an **Anchorpane** containing some labels,textfields and buttons.A new window is opened on clicking a button.After selecting name and id from new window, on pressing Enter button from keyboard window is closed and name and id is passed to already opened **Anchorpane**. I have to set the name and id on the labels of **Anchorpane**. I am getting the values but it is not setting in the labels without refreshing the anchorpane.

How can I again refresh the anchorpane without pressing any button for loading that anchorpane. I saw similiar questions, but nothing worked for me.

I passed data as below;

```
FXMLLoader load = new FXMLLoader();
                    try {
                        Pane root = load.load(getClass().getResource(FXML_CTRL_BILL).openStream());
                        Item_bill bill = load.getController();
                        bill.setDataCustomer(name, id);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

and I got the passed value here in my Item_bill controller as below

```
public void setDataCustomer(String name, String cutmrId) {

    Item_bill.customerName = name;
    Item_bill.customerId = cutmrId;

}
```

Values are setting only after calling initialize() method again.
How can I solve this without calling initialize() method again??

Can anyone help me. Thank You.

Comment: Could you  post a small example of how you pass the values to the AnchorPane? As I think your problem may he solved when using `ObservableValue`'s if you dont already.

Comment: What do you mean you need to "refresh" the `AnchorPane`??? You simply modify the `text` property of the existing `Label`s in that `AnchorPane`. That's all it takes to "refresh" those nodes...

Comment: @fabian-I want to set the values in labels of that anchorpane. But the values are setting only after loading the pane again. Means I have to call the initialize() method again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem as,
I made the reference to labels named custmrNameDummy and idLabelDummy  ,

```
@FXML
private Label custmrName;
public static Label custmrNameDummy;
@FXML
private Label idLabel;
public static Label idLabelDummy;
static String customerName = null;
static String customerId = null;


public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    custmrNameDummy=custmrName;
    idLabelDummy=idLabel;


}


public static void setDataCustomer(String name, String cutmrId) {

    Item_bill.customerName = name;
    Item_bill.customerId = cutmrId;

    custmrNameDummy.setText(customerName);
    idLabelDummy.setText(String.valueOf(customerId));

}
```

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately too late in order to help you with your problem described above but I had the same / a similiar problem and I solved it :-)

First of all a short explanation of my problem:

I have three TableViews:

> ("tblPreviousResults", "tblTotalStatistics", "tblAvailableCategories")

All tables are located on one AnchorPane and I wanted to trigger an update on the TableView "tblPreviousResults" depending on whether the CheckBoxTableCell (which is located in the TableView "tblAvailableCategories") is checked or not.

My first attempt (as I always have done):

> tblPreviousResults.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(newPreviousResults));
>   tblPreviousResults.refresh();

But the newPreviousResults didn't appear until I selected / focused the table directly.

Now I have a workaround solution for my problem:

> tblPreviousResults.getParent().requestFocus();

Maybe I can help someone :-)